# How to add button on custom MKAnnotationView

Tags: objective-c, mkmapview, mapkit, mkannotation

How i can add button on MKAnnotationView? I added title and subtitle but i not can add button? i don't understand why? How i can implement this?

I have class for custom MKAnnotationView

.h

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


    @interface AnnotationCellout : UIView
    @property (weak, nonatomic) UILabel *nameLabel;
    @property (weak, nonatomic) UILabel *infoLabel;
    @property (weak, nonatomic) UIButton *info;

    @end
```

.m

```
#import "AnnotationCellout.h"

@implementation AnnotationCellout

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self setupUI];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setupUI {
    // view
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.layer.borderColor = [UIColor purpleColor].CGColor;
    self.layer.borderWidth = .5;
    self.layer.cornerRadius = 5;

    // titleLabel
    UILabel *nameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(2, 2, self.frame.size.width - 4, 17)];
    nameLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    nameLabel.textColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
    nameLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14 weight:UIFontWeightBold];
    [self addSubview:nameLabel];
    self.nameLabel = nameLabel;

    // subtitleLabel
    UILabel *infoLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(2, 20, self.frame.size.width - 4, 30)];
    infoLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
    infoLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    infoLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    infoLabel.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    infoLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
    [self addSubview:infoLabel];
    self.infoLabel = infoLabel;

    UIButton *button         = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    button.frame             = CGRectMake(2, 20, self.frame.size.width - 4, 30);
    [button setTitle:@"OK" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(didTouchUpInsideCalloutButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self addSubview:_info];
    self.info = button;

}

@end
```

And i don't now how to add action for this button.

Comment: you added the action didTouchUpInsideCalloutButton to the button. What else do you need ?

Comment: @TejaNandamuri this button not show on Annotation, i see only title and subtitle. I can not add this button

Answer (score 0):

If You want button action on MKAnnotationView then You can use this delegate method.

Load Your data first in any Array( i am taking mapData) of Dictionary.
Then write this method for loading the annotation

```
-(void)loadAnnotation
{
    for (int i =0; i< [mapData count]; i++) {
        NSMutableDictionary *dict = [mapData objectAtIndex:i];
        double latitude = [[dict objectForKey:@"lat"]doubleValue];
         double longitude = [[dict objectForKey:@"lon"]doubleValue];
        CLLocationCoordinate2D coord;
        coord.latitude = latitude;
        coord.longitude = longitude;
        MKPointAnnotation *point = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
        point.coordinate = coord;
        point.title = [dict objectForKey:@"title"];
         point.subTitle = [dict objectForKey:@"subTitle"];
        [self.mapView addAnnotation:point];
    }

}
```

Then For Validatiing

```
  - (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
{

    MKPointAnnotation *testPoint = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
    testPoint = view.annotation;
    NSLog(@"The title is %@",testPoint.title);
    for (int i = 0; i<[mapData count]; i++) {
         NSMutableDictionary *dict = [mapData objectAtIndex:i];
        if ([[dict objectForKey:@"title"] isEqualToString:testPoint.title]) {
            NSLog(@"Hey I am clicked");//Perform your action Here
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: i have many Annotation, i load them from core data. And i need onclick button open detail view from this Annotation